# regex - exclude symbol from fixed pattern

Tags: php, regex

I need a help from some regular expression expert.

I have a script which give a fixed list of pattern. With very simple regular expression i search for pattern existence in target text. For example:

```
/.*TFT.*/
/.*LCD.*/
/.*ANTI-GLARE.*/
```

Those strings - TFT,LCD,ANTI-GLARE are fixed - I can't modify them. Well, the problem is in ANTI-GLARE - that dash will cause not to match AntiGlare. I know that id I make regex like this:

```
/.*ANTI-?GLARE.*/
```

this will match both variants, but i can't modify that string. My question is:
Is there another way to make symbol optional, than exclamation mark in pattern?

**EDIT - clearance**

After some answers and hints, i'll try to give more specific description of my problem.
I have a strings in table:

Anti Glare

```
TFT
AntiGlare
LCD
```

Via XML I receive new model which description is like:

> Anti-Glare

i need to ensure - did i have a entry with "Anti Glare" like description. I can not change that Anti-Glare received, because there a lot of strings - vary in wide range - it's impossible to build logical group or any like this in regex. it's build with php script like:

```
$rexp="/.*~.*/i";
```

- where ~ is replaced with that string.

  $rexp=str_replace('~',$rexp,$cond);
- where $cond holds current string received

  Operator can change any part outside that ~, but can not in ~ content - there will be a thousands of them

Comment: Question mark that follows the character is the way to go.

Comment: Also, remove these `.*`, they're useless and actually cause your regex to be slower

Comment: You could use regex OR /(ANTI-GLARE)|(ANTIGLARE)/ but that also involves modifying the regex.

Comment: Be careful, regex are case sensitive and `ANTI-?GLARE` will never match `AntiGlare`

Comment: In my explanation, all strings - pattern and target are always upper case - just for clearance. Of course, i use 'i' switch

Answer (score 2):

You're using php, so we can assume you've got something like an array with every strings accepted.

Here is a way to do what you want, if only dash bother you :

```
<?php

$words = array('TFT', 'LCD', 'ANTI-GLARE');
$pattern = '/(' . str_replace('-', '-?', implode($words, '|')) . ')/i';

?>
```

This will generate you the pattern `/(TFT|LCD|ANTI-?GLARE)/i`, [which will fit your needs](http://regex101.com/r/bZ7oE0/1).

**EDIT**

As mentioned in comments, you're receiving every possible strings : `TFT;LCD;AntiGlare;Anti-Glare;Anti Glare`. You then just have to concatenate them with a pipe (the OR operator in regex) and wrap he whole block with parenthesis :

```
$words = array('TFT', 'LCD', 'AntiGlare', 'Anti-Glare', 'Anti Glare');
$pattern = '/(' . implode($words, '|') . ')/i';
```

This will generate you the pattern `/(TFT|LCD|AntiGlare|Anti-Glare|Anti Glare)/i`

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want only with regular expression to cover that. Any script modifications is not well, because there will be situation when that symbols (dash in that case) must be treated exact, and in another situation - to be optional. Of course, if there is no way, i will modify php script.

Comment: How can you know if it's optional or not ?

Comment: pattern can be for example: Anti-Glare, AntiGlare OR Anti Glare. They arrive as variable which is concatenated to fixed part and form regex. Operator can modify that fixed regex part which is outside that variable. Variable content can be modified only via php script which I try to avoid.

Comment: So you'll receive something like `TFT;LCD;ANTIGLARE;ANTI-GLARE;ANTI GLARE` ?

Comment: Yes. And those strings goes to regex as is. I wish not to modify them.

Comment: Thank you again. Using OR is possible when I edit regex inner content - which i try to avoid. I realize that obviously what I want is impossible and will use your idea probably. I'll try to clear my question...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can not modify those regex, but I suppose you can modify the text. So, you can do this.

Use regex `/antiglare/` with case insensitive flag and then replace them with `ANTI-GLARE`. I hope this will work for you. I can't give you code, as I do not myself know php.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately - this will be solution only if that pattern list is fixed. But those pattern are dynamical - they arrive via XML, and i do not know - today i'll have Anti-Glare. Tomorrow can be Full-Size for example.